# tensorflow-serving-apis - cannot find python documentation

Tags: python, api, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have been trying to use tensorflow serving to serve a model and utilize tensorflow-serving-api as mentioned here: https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/tree/master/tensorflow_serving/apis
Im using python and try as I might, I could not find the documentation for the package. 
The [pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-serving-api/) redirects [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/) (tensorflow serving) which does not contain documentation of the python client wrapper. Neither does this place https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/api_docs/cc/

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5):

Tensorflow serving API for python is not documented that well. Easiest solution is to go throgh the examples they provide for serving below. The code is pretty simple

https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/tree/master/tensorflow_serving/example

Also you can checkout below blogs that explain serving very well through gRCP.

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-deploy-tensorflow-models-to-production-using-tf-serving-4b4b78d41700